# mysqli query not working when variable inserted

Tags: php, mysqli

I need an extra pair of eyes! I have a super-simple query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT post_id FROM blog_posts WHERE post_uri = 'the-test-post' LIMIT 1");
$row = $result->fetch_array();
```

and this gives me the post_id. However, if I insert a variable for post_uri, the result is empty. Ways I tried of which none worked:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT post_id FROM blog_posts WHERE post_uri = '".$post_uri."' LIMIT 1");


$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT post_id FROM blog_posts WHERE post_uri = ".$post_uri." LIMIT 1");


$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT post_id FROM blog_posts WHERE post_uri = $post_uri LIMIT 1");
```

I have similar query on another page working just right, so that confuses me even more. Help appreciated.

Comment: resistance to literal inlining is probably just an attempt to hint you to bind parameters: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters?langtype=php#tab_4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are slapping a variable directly into a query. This is error prone (as you are discovering) and has a high risk that you'll fail to sufficiently sanitise it (and thus cause an SQL injection vulnerability).

Use [the PDO layer and bound variables](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: Thanks for this very valuable info.

Comment: Turned out the error was caused by my syntax omission in INSERT query preceding the one I asked about here, and this omission wouldn't even have a chance of happening when approach suggested here is used. Plus it's more secure. Thanks again, really!

Answer (score 3):

If you put that query in a string and echo it, you can check what happens. There might be something wrong with that variable!

```
echo "SELECT post_id FROM blog_posts WHERE post_uri = '".$post_uri."' LIMIT 1";
```

And so on. I'll bet there's either nothing, or something you're not expecting in that $post_uri, because it shouldn't matter to mysql *how* you've build your query.

Comment: Thanks for this neat trick, it showed me that query is perfectly fine and I'm obviously messing things somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Your syntax looks fine. Try to use a simple version of the 
db connection call. Below are compared the version that worked (above) to the one
that failed (below).

```
$sqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db')
```

I had use a variable in my query and had a `$mysqli->real_connect` db connection.
That would not work. But when I switched to the `new mysqli` type I was surprised 
that the variable query did work.

I hope that works out for you.

Comment: $con->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0') is likely your issue.  The code example on Php's documentation shows that and many people copy it without realizing the implications.

Comment: 'tis getting a little dim by now, but what you say is ringing bells. I am in fact quite certain my code relating to real_connect did come straight from the man[UAL]. And yes, it included the MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND. The db stuff is rather touchy and trying :)